# Is there a way to link the source Dataverse via ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have been trying to select a source that is not SQL in ADF Data Flows. Specifically the CDS (Dataverse). This used to be possible but is no longer possible.

Has this feature been removed from ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Dataverse isn't supported as Source or Sink in Data Flow now. You can find the supported list here

Source type:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#supported-sources

Sink type:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#supported-sinks